Re-calculate accuracy, precision and recall after treatment effect in a model
Working in a churn-prediction model where the goal is to detect the players that have a high chance to churn from the site and send those players an offer to keep them in site.
In the initial training stage there is no offers being sent to the players so you can train the model (in this case a classifier) to determine 1 if lapsing or 0 if not. Using standards metrics like accuracy, precision, recall, f1 etc, you pick the best model and then deploy.
Now, once the model is in place your detected players will receive an offer, let say that after a few months you want to re-calculate your model metrics to asses if the model need to be re-trained, the problem now is that there is a treatment modifying the behaviours of the players, so if the model predicts to lapse (1 in this case) then you send an offer and then checking the actual value you could see a 0 (didn't lapse) which may means the offer managed to keep the player from lapsing. The data would look like this now:



user_id
churn_prediction
actual_churn




200
0
0


201
1
0


202
1
1



From the table you could see for example that user_id 201 was predicted to churn so he would have received a treatment at that moment, then when we check the actual/real status after x amount of time we can see the user stayed on site. The problem is that for classifier metrics, this churn_prediction of 1 and actual_churn of 0 would be considered as a bad prediction, but in reality the real behaviour of the player could have been changed by the treatment to be 0 (which is good for purpose of the system, but we don't know if the model actually got it wrong or treatment was the one that affected this result). Cases where there was not treatment (predicted=0) shouldn't affect as I can properly measure if the model predicted correctly checking the actual, but cases where there was a treatment would be difficult to estimate if model was correct or not. This would for sure affect all the classification metrics, which would make harder to properly asses the pure performance of the model for re-training/monitoring purposes.
I know I can measure other metrics related to the system as a whole like for example, maybe the offer is not best and it need to be changed, but if I only want to asses the performance of the model, my question is how to re-calculate the metrics taking into account the effect of the treatment so I can asses the current performance of the model for a re-training/monitoring purpose.
